# Sails session not saved in browser

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

I have a starting project with Sails (0.12.13, node v7.2.0) as an api endpoint. I have a really simple UserController containing 2 actions :

```
me: function(req, res)
{   
    console.log(req.session.authenticated,req.session.userId);
},

autologin: function(req, res)
{   
    req.session.authenticated = true;
    req.session.userId = 18;

    return res.ok('login_ok');
}
```

Here are my route config file

```
'GET /me': 'UserController.me',
'PUT /autologin': 'UserController.autologin'
```

When I use postman to call `/autologin` then `/me` everything works fine. On the other hand, when I do the same with jquery in my front end, the `/me` call after `/autologin` can't retrieve sessions as the console show `undefined undefined` like if sessions weren't saved.

The frontend code example :

```
loginInSails: function(code)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: sailsServerUrl + '/autologin'
    })
    .fail(function(a) 
    {  
        console.log(a);
    })
    .done(function(d)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: sailsServerUrl + '/me'
        })
        .fail(function(a) 
        {  
            console.log(a);
        })
        .done(function(d)
        {
            console.log(d);
        });
    });
}
```

Not the first time I use Sails, never saw this. If you need more details about the environment just ask and I will provide them.

Comment: I'm having similar issue, however, mine only happens on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

add this on every request.

```
withCredentials: true
```

Angular 1:

```
$http({
    url: serviceURL,
    method: method,
    withCredentials: true,
    params: q
})
```

Jquery:

```
xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
}

loginInSails: function(code)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: sailsServerUrl + '/autologin',
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
        }
    })
    .fail(function(a) 
    {  
        console.log(a);
    })
    .done(function(d)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: sailsServerUrl + '/me',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        })
        .fail(function(a) 
        {  
            console.log(a);
        })
        .done(function(d)
        {
            console.log(d);
        });
    });
}
```